# Unable to run cudaminer on jetson

Tags: nvidia, gcc, cuda

After downloading and running ./autogen.sh and ./configure execution of the make command gives the following error on my Jetson TK1

> gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -msse2  -fopenmp -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -I./compat/jansson -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_CHOOSE_COMPILETIME   -g -O2 -MT cudaminer-cpu-miner.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cudaminer-cpu-miner.Tpo -c -o cudaminer-cpu-miner.o `test -f 'cpu-miner.c' || echo './'`cpu-miner.cgcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’make[2]: *** [cudaminer-cpu-miner.o] Error 1make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/CudaMiner-master'make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/ubuntu/CudaMiner-master'make: *** [all] Error 2

Don't know what to do next, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've some (highly) experimental bits for Jetson TK1 in https://github.com/noxo/CudaMiner. Error here (unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’) is because code compilation is done using SSE instructions, which is not available ARM architecture (NEON should be used instead).